# In Franck-Hertz experiment, why mercury emits UV light while neon emits visible light despite neon having greater excitation energy?

Tags: energy, atomic-physics, potential-energy, photon-emission

The reference that I checked shows that Neon has an excitation energy of 18.2 eV, while mercury has 4.9 eV. However, the reference also shows that the wavelength emitted by the mercury is at the ultraviolet range of the electromagnetic spectrum (254 nm precisely). How could this be, despite Neon having greater excitation energy than mercury?

Answer (score 1):

There are three energy levels in play. And the visible light is emitted due to the smaller gap. So the visible light that we see is actually from a $3p\to3s$ transition which has an energy gap of around $1.7$ eV.

[image]